# Which design pattern should I use? (Payment system API)

Tags: design-patterns

I have to implement classes that work with payment system (let's call it PaymentSystem) API that allow operations listed below:

- Issue an invoice to the user
- Check the invoice
- Get users balance
- Check payee existence

What I've got now is:

abstract class `PaymentSystemBase` where all the settings are remain (security token, password, RESTful APIs URL, etc.)

a class for each API entry:

- `PaymentSystemIssueInvoice`
- `PaymentSystemCheckInvoice`
- `PaymentSystemGetBalance`
- `PaymentSystemCheckUser`

each of this classes are inherited from `PaymentSystemAPI` with methods  (inherited from PaymentSystemBase, of course):

- `request` - performs request over HTTP
- `parseResponse` to parse response from API (basically tells whether request was successful or we've got an error)

So my question is: would it be convenient to use some creation design pattern for the APIs (`IssueInvoice`, `CheckInvoice`, `GetBalance`, `CheckUser`)?

If you have suggestion for me how I should've implemented the API in the another way, please feel free to answer/comment the question.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you're already implementing the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)?

Comment: Yes, but it's a behavioral pattern. I'm looking forward to encapsulate  those classes to not to use them directly, but via common interface, something like this (I'm thinking of it): `PaymentSystem.apiCall.getBalance(params)` (pseudo-code). What apiCall does is: creates PaymentSystemGetBalance instance with `params`, then calls `request` and returns instance of `PaymentSystemGetBalance` (kind of a mix of `factory` and `builder`)

Comment: and the point is: if I add another API, let's say, `PaymentSystemDeclineIvoice`, I will still use it via this common interface (`PaymentSystem.apiCall.DeclineInvoice(params)`), which seems to be convenient to me. Although I'm not an expert in design patterns, so I'm not aware of any drawbacks here if go this way. Kind of a bloated question - I realize that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be similar to [command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) (noted by Irfy).

If you have complex logic that determines which subclass of a base class to use (i.e. more than is reasonable to do with a few constructor params), then you can use the [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) pattern.

I'll throw [strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) out there as well, but we may be getting off-track.

As a general note on design patterns, you should use them with a purpose. Typically patterns are used to:

1. Increase code readability
2. Increase code reusability.
3. Separate what may change from what will not change.

In particular, if the subclasses you are choosing may change in the future, it is good to abstract the code that decided which one to use. The factory pattern does this by encapsulating this logic in a single class.

I strikes me as odd that you are using a handful of classes to represent what looks like methods. But, it sounds like you're working with another API, so I'd need more info to advise further.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I appreciate it. please, see my responds to @lrfy. `sounds like you're working with another API`. YEP. `so I'd need more info to advise further`. Well, the documentation is in Russian, unfortunately :) The scheme works this way: we issue an invoice to the payee, then he logs in into a system, pays and get back to our website, we also can check status of the invoice and check payee existence. After he paid/or refused, merchant (the payment system) notifies us (HTTP call to our website). That's pretty much it, I don't know what else info I can provide here.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I may have to give this one to the coding gods. Unless I can see some code or UML or something, I don't feel confident making suggestions. It also became clear that you're familiar with basic design patterns, so your situation might be unique.

Comment: Not to mention I don't know what language you're using =P

Comment: This is not unique for sure :) This is all about my obsession with perfect code lol. As I re-though my tendencies for perfection, the problem has self-disappeared, all in all there is refactoring for a rescue. `The factory pattern does this by encapsulating this logic in a single class`. I decided to go with slightly modified `Factory Pattern`, which means I can accept your answer ;)

Comment: Awesome! Congrats on figuring it out. I, too, am obsessive about architecture perfection...

Comment: `Not to mention I don't know what language you're using =P` I use both Russian and PHP, sometimes I speak Python and Java and I really do like pseudo-code and English primarily because of large society.

Comment: Ah, the perfectionist :-) Was one myself, until I realized that my perversion for perfect code made it *less* readable. Seriously, I used to factorize my code so much, that nothing would be redundant, everything would be perfect, but also, no one would be able to read the code any more. I learned to find the fine line between perfect factorization of code and imperfect, but very readable and understandable code. The general lesson I learned was "If it doesn't *smell*, don't fix it". This leaves your code simple and readable at the cost of an imperfection here and there.

Comment: Haha Irfy. I thought of writing a similar comment, since I've seen people use a million design patterns when it really wasn't useful beyond confusing the reader.